# Look up value between dates

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tables. One table contains a column with dates and a column with exchange rates. A second table allows a user to enter any date and returns the exchange rate from the other table.

The lookup between the dates should search for the date that is closest to the entered date but never a future date (past or same date). How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [vlookup](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318?hl=en) is for.

```
=vlookup(D2, A2:B, 2, True)
```

Here D2 is search key, A2:B the range in which to search (1st column is searched), 2 is the number of column from which to return the result. True means the following:

> If is_sorted is TRUE or omitted, the nearest match (less than or equal to the search key) is returned. If all values in the search column are greater than the search key, #N/A is returned.

Also works as an arrayformula, looking up all D values at once:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(D2:D3, A2:B, 2, True))
```